# PHP: Use global variables from include file

Tags: php, include, global-variables

There are a lot of similar questions, but I couldn't get it to work:
I try to use global variables in an include file like this:

included.php:

```
<?php
  function some_function()
  {
     $GLOBALS['username'] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"];
  }
?>
```

first.php:

```
<?php
  include 'included.php';
  some_function()

  echo '<p>Hello ' . $GLOBALS['username'] . '!'</p>'
?>
```

second.php:

```
<?php
  include 'included.php';

  echo '<p>Hello ' . $GLOBALS['username'] . '!'</p>'
?>
```

The output of first.php works just fine, but in second.php there is an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: student_firstname in /var/www/students/reservations.php on line 36

So my goal is to use this global variable 'username' all over my project and I don't want to call some_function() every time, because there are more variables with SQL queries, so this would take too long.

Is there a nice way to do this or can you recommend me another way?
Thank you!

Comment: it's bad design when you need to use global variables. you should try to avoid this approach

Comment: So what would you suggest?
That I always execute the SQL query when I need the variable?

Comment: So the problem is that the variable is not getting set when you don't call the function... Then what about calling the function inside `included.php`, or not wrap the code in a function that needs to be called separately to begin with? Also yes, globals are bad practice. You should prepare that variable once and then pass it into functions as needed.

Comment: implement an interface that builds underlying cache layer. So when you call `getUser()` it stores a copy from the previous call and return the result. You should also invest time in building a cache invalidator for this system to work well.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a keyword `global` for that purpose. But it is considered to be a really bad practice and violation of encapsulation etc.

```
$username = "Test" ;

function some_function(){
  global $username ;  //Put a global variable into current space.
  echo $username ;    //Now you can access the global variable.
}
```

P.S. learn to pass your variables into functions as parameters, for it will make your life really easy.

Answer (score -1):

You could use PHP Sessions,
for example on your index page have the code;

```
<?PHP  
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$_SERVER["REMOTE_USER"];
?>
```

then on top of all your pages you will need to put;

```
<?PHP  
session_start();
?>
```

above the  tag.

Then you can call the username by simply

```
<?PHP echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> and that will display their username.
```

Source: Been a PHP/HTML/CSS Developer for 3 years.